# Can't add WSL Node Interpreter to WebStorm

Tags: webstorm, windows-subsystem-for-linux, jetbrains-ide

I need to add  WSL node interpreter to WebStorm (2020.1) but Linux distribution is not detected by WebStorm, even though I have **Alpine** **WSL** install through Windows Store.

I read [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1440464/jetbrains-webstorm-not-detecting-installed-linux-distributions-for-windows-subsy), but no help. Also manually adding entry in `wsl.distributions.xml` didn't work, did a lot of research but nothing worked.

I was able to use WSL as terminal in WebStorm by adding wsl.exe location to shell path. My objective is to run npm scripts form from Run/Debug configuration.

[image: Linux distribution not detectable]

Answer (score 0):

I solved by reinstalling WebStorm and copying options folder
from  `C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\WebStorm2020.1`
to    `C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\JetBrains\WebStorm2020.1`, then  WebStorm could detect Linux distribution installed on machine.

But, now when I am trying to run scripts from *NPM Tool Window* of WebStorm, WebStorm runs  `C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe run "/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js run start --scripts-prepend-node-path=auto"` where ***run*** is redundant coming  after `C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe ...`

How can I set WebStorm to not have ***run*** in `wsl.exe run ...`?